# Figure captions in Word with R Markdown source and pandoc conversion

Tags: markdown, knitr, rstudio, pandoc, r-markdown

I'm writing a report in Rmarkdown language with Rstudio, and then I convert the `md` file (not the `Rmd`file)  into `doc` format using pandoc.
Each figure has a caption in the output `doc` file: *"plot of chunk unnamed-chunk-xxx"*. Of course I can modify this caption in the `md`file, but I wonder whether it is possible to directly modify it in the `Rmd`file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ooops I have found a solution: option `fig.cap` of the R chunk.
The caption appears in the Word file after conversion, but it does not appear in the html file.